# ZendSearch Lucene class not found

Tags: php, lucene, zend-framework2, search-engine, zend-search-lucene

I was following [this](http://packtlib.packtpub.com/library/9781782161929/ch07lvl1sec68) book to install the ZendSearh on the application, I did exactly as it's written and I'm getting a Fatal error: Class 'ZendSearch\Lucene\Lucene' not found in /var/www/CommunicationApp/module/Users/src/Users/Controller/SearchController.php on line 107

```
<?php
namespace Users\Controller;

use Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController;
use Zend\View\Model\ViewModel;

use Zend\Http\Headers;

use Zend\Authentication\AuthenticationService;
use Zend\Authentication\Adapter\DbTable as DbTableAuthAdapter;

use Users\Form\RegisterForm;
use Users\Form\RegisterFilter;

use Users\Model\User;
use Users\Model\UserTable;
use Users\Model\Upload;

use Users\Model\ImageUpload;
use Users\Model\ImageUploadTable;

use ZendSearch\Lucene;
use ZendSearch\Lucene\Document;
use ZendSearch\Lucene\Index;

class SearchController extends AbstractActionController
{
    protected $storage;
    protected $authservice;

    public function getAuthService()
    {
        if (! $this->authservice) {
            $this->authservice = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('AuthService');
        }
        return $this->authservice;
    }

    public function getIndexLocation()
    {
        // Fetch Configuration from Module Config
        $config  = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('config');
        if ($config instanceof Traversable) {
            $config = ArrayUtils::iteratorToArray($config);
        }
        if (!empty($config['module_config']['search_index'])) {
            return $config['module_config']['search_index'];
        } else {
            return FALSE;
        }
    }

    public function getFileUploadLocation()
    {
        // Fetch Configuration from Module Config
        $config  = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('config');
        if ($config instanceof Traversable) {
            $config = ArrayUtils::iteratorToArray($config);
        }
        if (!empty($config['module_config']['upload_location'])) {
            return $config['module_config']['upload_location'];
        } else {
            return FALSE;
        }
    }   

    public function indexAction()
    {
        $request = $this->getRequest();
        if ($request->isPost()) {
            $queryText = $request->getPost()->get('query');
            $searchIndexLocation = $this->getIndexLocation();
            $index = Lucene\Lucene::open($searchIndexLocation);
            $searchResults = $index->find($queryText);
        }

        // prepare search form
        $form  = new \Zend\Form\Form();
        $form->add(array(
            'name' => 'query',
            'attributes' => array(
                'type'  => 'text',
                'id' => 'queryText',
                'required' => 'required'
            ),
            'options' => array(
                'label' => 'Search String',
            ),
        ));
        $form->add(array(
            'name' => 'submit',
            'attributes' => array(
                'type'  => 'submit',
                'value' => 'Search', 
                'style' => "margin-bottom: 8px; height: 27px;"
            ),
        ));

        $viewModel  = new ViewModel(array('form' => $form, 'searchResults' => $searchResults));
        return $viewModel;
    }


    public function generateIndexAction()
    {
        $searchIndexLocation = $this->getIndexLocation();
        $index = Lucene\Lucene::create($searchIndexLocation); // line 107

        $userTable = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('UserTable');
        $uploadTable = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('UploadTable');
        $allUploads = $uploadTable->fetchAll();  
        foreach($allUploads as $fileUpload) {
            //
            $uploadOwner = $userTable->getUser($fileUpload->user_id);

            // id field
            $fileUploadId= Document\Field::unIndexed('upload_id', $fileUpload->id);
            // label field
            $label = Document\Field::Text('label', $fileUpload->label);
            // owner field          
            $owner = Document\Field::Text('owner', $uploadOwner->name);


            if (substr_compare($fileUpload->filename, ".xlsx", strlen($fileUpload->filename)-strlen(".xlsx"), strlen(".xlsx")) === 0) {
                // index excel sheet
                $uploadPath    = $this->getFileUploadLocation();
                $indexDoc = Lucene\Document\Xlsx::loadXlsxFile($uploadPath ."/" . $fileUpload->filename);
            } else if (substr_compare($fileUpload->filename, ".docx", strlen($fileUpload->filename)-strlen(".docx"), strlen(".docx")) === 0) {
                // index word doc
                $uploadPath    = $this->getFileUploadLocation();
                $indexDoc = Lucene\Document\Docx::loadDocxFile($uploadPath ."/" . $fileUpload->filename);
            } else {
                $indexDoc = new Lucene\Document();
            }
            $indexDoc->addField($label);
            $indexDoc->addField($owner);
            $indexDoc->addField($fileUploadId);
            $index->addDocument($indexDoc);
        }
        $index->commit();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

It has its own repository on github.

https://github.com/zendframework/ZendSearch

You have to load it via composer or just download and put it under vendor folder.

Comment: What did you do? Composer or Download?